# Laravel Eloquent: get dialog based on messages

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have `messages` table with structure like: `id`, `to_id`, `from_id` ...
I need to write Eloquent query that gives me dialogs for specific user as result. Every dialog should have one last message (no matter incoming or sent) and all ordered by ctreated_at desc.

For example getting whole dialog by id of companion:

```
        $messages = Message::with(array_keys($fields->getRelations()))
        ->select($select)
        ->whereRaw('from_id = ? and to_id = ? ', [auth()->id(), $args['user_id']])
        ->orWhereRaw('from_id = ? and to_id = ? ', [$args['user_id'], auth()->id()])
        ->orderByDesc('created_at');
```

But before that i need a list of dialogs available to get.

Trying
`$dialogUsers = Message::where('to_id', auth()->id())
  ->orWhere('from_id', auth()->id())
  ->select(['from_id', 'to_id'])
  ->distinct();`
but i need to get messages too and in desc order